# Chapter No. in Theorem style

Tags: environments, theorems, framed

I'm using `\documentclass{book}`. I'm also using the code below to create a theorem style, however, it only puts the title on top. I want to modify the code so that I get => Theorem ch. no. theorem no. and then title. (For instance => Theorem 1.1 The Title). Any ideas how to modify the code? Here is a MWE. [Note: `\tcolorbox` doesn't work for me, that's why I'm using the code below :-) ] I want something similar to the picture below but without `\tcolorbox`.[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\def\myindent{1.5ex}
\def\rulethk{1.0pt}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{32,92,195}
\newenvironment{mybox}[1]
  {\par\medskip\noindent\arrayrulewidth=2pt\arrayrulecolor{myblue}%
   \tabularx{\linewidth}{!{\color{myblue}\hspace{\myindent}\vrule width \rulethk} X @{}}
   \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\tabular{@{}l@{}}\textbf{#1}\\\hline\endtabular}\\}
  {\\\color{myblue}\hspace{\myindent}\smash{\rule[.5pt]{10ex}{\rulethk}}\endtabularx\par\smallskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{The title with some more text in the title}
Only some text here
\end{mybox}

\blindtext

\begin{mybox}{The title}
\blindtext
\end{mybox}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: And the theorems inside the MWE, where are they?

Comment: @Aradnix: It shouldn't be necessarily a theorem. Please assume "Only some text here" is the content of the theorem.

Comment: I think it's necessary since there are few packages for create theorems and I'm not sure what are you using for yours. In fact, your MWE forgot the AMS packages such as `amsmath`.

Comment: @Aradnix: Look, I guess there is a misunderstanding. I'm not going to use any packages for theorem. I want the title to automatically put a Theorem and the chapter no (as I explained) then any content as title and any content as the main text. Just want to have the phrase "Theorem 1.1" in the beginning ...

Comment: So you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Well, so as @Bernard says or you want to reinvent the wheel or complicate your life numbering your theorems manually or I don't know. My advice is to take a look at the [tools for theorems](http://www.ctan.org/ctan-portal/search/?phrase=theorem) and if you don't like to use any package, it's fine, then you can program your own. Good luck.

Comment: @Bernard: I don't know what you're talking about! Please look at the figure I added. I need to create a theorem style similar to the one in the picture.

Comment: @Aradnix: Please see my comment to Bernard and the picture above!

Comment: I saw it, copy the code from your MWE and compiled on my computer. That's why I asked about the environment for theorem that you did not include. As you do not seem interested in using some package for this and you want to solve it manually I do not see what the problem is. But if I were you would use a combination of `ntheorem` and `pstricks` or perhaps `ntheorem` and your own environment to enclose it in a color box.

Comment: @Aradnix: Like I said, I cannot follow. Use any package you like except `\tcolorbox` to create what you see in the picture. I need a theorem style as given in the picture. So, what is unclear to you?

Comment: QBernard: Did you see the pic? Can you create such a thing without `\tcolorbox`, tell me you solution.

Comment: @LartexQuest: Take a look at the `thmbox` package doc — but it does not seem to be very customisable.

Comment: Relax and see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just like an example of what we can do with a package suited for theorems and that stuff, belong your MWE with few additions:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym} % necessary for maths    
\usepackage{ntheorem} % One of the best packages for write theorems, proofs, defintions, etc. 
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont} % For modify the body font in the theorems
\theoremstyle{break} % One of the styles for theorems
\usepackage{blindtext}
\def\myindent{1.5ex}
\def\rulethk{1.0pt}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{32,92,195}
\newenvironment{mybox}[1]
  {\par\medskip\noindent\arrayrulewidth=2pt\arrayrulecolor{myblue}%
   \tabularx{\linewidth}{!{\color{myblue}\hspace{\myindent}\vrule width \rulethk} X @{}}
   \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\tabular{@{}l@{}}\textbf{#1}\\\hline\endtabular}\\}
  {\\\color{myblue}\hspace{\myindent}\smash{\rule[.5pt]{10ex}{\rulethk}}\endtabularx\par\smallskip}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorema}[section] % Definition of the sets of theorems we need. Notice the option section, necessary for what you want
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}[section]
\newtheorem{define}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Theorems} 

\begin{mybox}{}
\section{The title with some more text in the title}
Only some text here
\end{mybox}

\blindtext

\begin{mybox}{}
\begin{define}[Tautology]\label{def:tautology}
A \emph{tautology} is a proposition that is always true for any value of its variables.
\end{define}

\begin{define}[Contradiction]\label{def:contradiction}
A \emph{contradiction} is a proposition that is always false for any value of its variables.
\end{define} 
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{}
\section{The title}
\blindtext
\end{mybox}

\blindtext

\begin{mybox}{}
\begin{theo}
If proposition $P$ is a tautology then $\sim P$ is a contradiction, and conversely.
\begin{proof}
If $P$ is a tautology, then all elements of its truth table are true (by Definition~\ref{def:tautology}), so all elements of the truth table for $\sim P$ are false, therefore $\sim P$ is a contradiction (by Definition~\ref{def:contradiction}).
\end{proof}
\end{theo} 
\end{mybox}   

\end{document}
```

For a better understood of what I did, please check the [package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem). I used the examples [from here](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/ntheorem.html) (listing 13). Notice that instead of use the `standard` option of the package, that loads few basic and standard names, I created my own.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I used your `mybox` environment instead of the `\newframedtheorem` (section 2.3.7) of the package, because it needs to load the `pstricks` package and I don't use it. The only modification is that I let empty the second argument of your environment, because for this I don't need it, but I didn't modified the code.

I see you're in your obstinacy of not wanting to add any package for theorems. It's fine, it's your decision, I just wanted to show the possibilities of the package, but if you prefer to keep battling this manually I wish you luck and patience, you'll need them.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't look like what I want at all. I want the same frame shape.

Comment: Well I think you have enough feedback for adapt it for look exactly as you want. If not you can ask again with more detail.

Comment: What do you mean by more detail? I think what I want is clearly mentioned and is shown in the picture. You reply doesn't look like what I want at all. The

Comment: @LatexQuest Well, I saw the picture from your MWE and use the same code with the nthorem package but is not what you want. If you want to program your own definition to create theorems and mix it with the environment you defined in your preamble, then check the link to packages for theorems which I send in a previous comment, review the documentation of the packages and check the code (in particular take a look at Frank Mittelbach `theorem` package), use what serves you and good luck.

Comment: Solved it using `\thmbox`.